# Windows 8.1 installation fail 0xC1900101 - 0x40017

Tags: installation, windows-8.1

I want to make a Windows store application using the monogame libraries, but for this purpose, I need to install Windows 8.1. The installation fails and gives me the error 
0xC1900101 - 0x40017

This error is quite large and alot of people have had or still have it. I made alot of research on it and it seems that this problem is caused by driver incompatibility. I tried the installation about 15 times now, every time updating some drivers, installing updates, etc.

On the installation, it stops at 84% on "Applying PC parameters" step.

So I believe that the problem is that one of my drivers in incompatible and I need to remove it so here are my specs/peripherals:

ASUS G75VW qs71 laptop (16GB RAM, i7 ivy bridge) (I don't think it is the problem, since my friend has the same and it worked for him)
- Logitech G930 Gaming Headset
- Razer Orochi Mouse (Not the 2013, but the 2012)

If some of these drivers are incompatible, please tell me how to remove them.

Thank you.

P.S. I'm not sure if this question is relevant for this site, but it is somewhat programming related and I need it to do programmation.

Comment: upload the setup logs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824819.aspx

Comment: Same here with a brand new Samsung Series 5 laptop. Did you resolve this issue and if so, how?